# Can you have "conditions" + "to" + infinitive of the main verb, and what does it mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I have come across the following sentence, which uses the word *conditions* + *to* + the infinitive form of the main verb:

> What are the conditions at the work place to create a productive work environment?

Now I'm wondering if this sentence is correct, and, if so, what exactly it means. When I look up the word *condition* in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conditions) and [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/condition), I can't find this particular construction (word+*to*+infinitive form of the main verb) with this word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, the sentence is not perfectly natural. The author probably meant "... the conditions [that can] create a productive work environment," or "conditions [intended] to create," or "conditions [intentionally put in place] to create." Context might help make the point clear, but it probably would have been better to choose one of these clearer constructions.

Comment: OR *What are the conditions **creating** [the **current** productive work environment]?* Without more context, we can only guess, which is probably all the proof we need to say the cited text is poor quality.